# Allow Access of ASPX Pages Only by Web API Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In an ASP.net Web Site project, which contains ASPX pages and also Web API (2.0) controllers, how can I disallow access to the ASPX pages from the network, but still allow the Web API code in App_Code to render them using `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute()`?

The use case would be to in a case where I want to return an HTML page (perhaps converted to a PDF) from a controller action, but I want it to always be filtered through the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all I need to do is simply deny access to all users in web.config, using `<deny users="*" />` and only allowing access to the API routes. The API code isn't restricted from accessing the pages based on web.config settings.